# "From here, to there" quote meaning

Tags: quotes, idiom-meaning

I read a story which used *"From here, to there"* as a love measurement. Does it mean distance or time period.

In the story *"From here"* was used when they where happy, with no worries in their life. As the story moved on they had complications, they lost trust for each other and they parted ways. After half a year the one who said *"From here"* was depressed and on the brick of no returning when she wrote *"To there"* to the other person.

What does this quote mean ?

Comment: Could you include a few sentences from where you found it? It should help get a better answer.

Comment: I think it mean any where you'll go there is something funny every where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is possible, especially if the character was speaking, that he was using it as a term of measurement, comparing two long distances to the amount love he feels for the other person.

It would be roughly the equivalent of a child holding his arms outstretched as far as he can, saying *"I love you **this** much."*

Comment: Forgive me that here I am assuming the one who is being metaphorical is a male; I don't mean to be chauvinist, but being raised in the Western tradition, I have grown up conditioned into believing that it is the man's job to be romantic, and put in the effort to win over the heart of the other.

Answer (score 0):

> “From there to here, from here to there, funny things are everywhere!”

― Dr. Seuss, One Fish, Two Fish, Red Fish, Blue Fish

http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/19784-from-there-to-here-from-here-to-there-funny-things
http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Dr._Seuss

See also:

> “From there to here, from here to there, funny things are everywhere” . . . So begins this classic Beginner Book by Dr. Seuss. Beginning with just five fish and continuing into flights of fancy, One Fish Two Fish Red Fish Blue Fish celebrates how much fun imagination can be. From the can-opening Zans to the boxing Gox to the winking Yink who drinks pink ink, the silly rhymes and colorful cast of characters create an entertaining approach to reading that will have every child giggling from morning to night: “Today is gone. Today was fun. Tomorrow is another one.”
>   
>   Originally created by Dr. Seuss, Beginner Books encourage children to read all by themselves, with simple words and illustrations that give clues to their meaning.

http://www.amazon.ca/One-Fish-Two-Red-Blue/dp/0394800133

Answer (score 0):

It is about a child's perspective, meaning everything is fascinating, amazing and amusing from both directions.
That I am sure of.